# Phonegap 1.8.1 Application with Sencha Touch 2 Starts only once

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have an issue deploying Sencha Touch 2.0.1.1 application with Phonegap 1.8.1 wrapper (Phonehap build) on Android.

When application runs after **sencha productuion build** without Phonegap api everything is fine.
But when Phonegap api is added to the application it runs only once.
When I close the app and open it again i see only loading indicator and nothing happens.

I add Phonegap api this way:

```
"js": [
            {   
        "path": "phonegap/cordova-1.8.1.js",
        "update": "full"
    },
    {
        "path": "sdk/sencha-touch.js",
        "update": "full"
    },
    {
        "path": "app.js",
        "bundle": true,  /* Indicates that all class dependencies are concatenated into this file when build */
        "update": "full"
    }
],
```

I don't even use api functions in my app. Just add js file to build.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... After a few days of troubles i found out that the reason is microloader. When i add javascript files with sencha microloader the app runs only once. If i add files manually by adding script tags to index.html everything is fine. In general there are lots of strange things with microloader especially production version...

Answer (score 0):

What android api version do you use? i am testing on 15 and 10.

at 10 i can confirm that an app only runs ones after install, if you use sencha build (production, testing). with api 15 there is no such ... behavior.

Comment: HTC Desire with Android 2.3.3. However we desided not to use the sencha microloader at all.

Comment: thats a hard decision. sencha build boosts performance a lot.

Comment: We desided not to use microloader script only, not the sencha build procedure itself.